# Formula value on chart only shows value for last grouped date

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, subreport

(see attached chart) I'm trying to get the furthest right column (Transfused) values to appear on the chart for the correct month.  The values at the top of the report are correct; the chart only shows the last month's value for all months.  This line is darkened on the chart for visibility.

The other 3 columns are running totals. The Transfused column is a calculated formula.  The chart is in a subreport.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wTDW.png)

I've tried passing shared values; recalculating in the subreport; saving the values from the running totals in the main report in formulas with shared values again and picking them up in the subreport.